# How to efficiently query the event viewer

Tags: .net, optimization, filtering, event-viewer

I can easily write to an event log and also read its content. However, I would like to be able to query only a subset of the event viewer, mainly the source I created within a specific time frame.

From what I can see, it's possible to filter by machine name  and source, (I have yet to make it work for some reason it always return everything from the Application log) but not by date and time.

I was able to do it easily using LINQ. However, it still look over the whole Application log so it takes a while. As time will go by, I guess the number of event in the Event Viewer will just get bigger and bigger so I don't see that getting better.

Is there a way to query the event viewer by more than the usual parameters to speed up the process or will I have to 'live with it'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests with WMI and turns out to be a nice enough solution when I have a small subset of results.

```
Dim oMag As New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT User, Type,TimeGenerated,Message FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE LogFile = 'Application' AND SourceName = 'Journalisation' AND TimeGenerated >= '20121031180000.000000-000' AND TimeGenerated <= '20121031181500.000000-000'")
Dim oMagColl As Management.ManagementObjectCollection = oMag.Get

For Each oMagObj As Management.ManagementObject In oMagColl
    Msgbox(oMagObj("User") & vbTab & oMagObj("Type") & vbTab & oMagObj("TimeGenerated") & vbTab & oMagObj("Message"))    
Next
```

Only think I find weird about it is the datetime format. Also, sometime it feels like the whole thing is taking a long time for no apparant reason.

In any case, I think this is a good solution.